# How to get the attribute of outer tag property from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, directory

```
    <html dir="LTR">
    <head></head>
    <body> 
      <iframe id="id_description_iframe" class="rte-zone" height="200" frameborder="0" title="description">
        <html>
          <head>
            <script>
              alert('document.querySelector("html").dir');
            </script>
          </head>
          <body class="frameBody">
            test<br/>
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </body>
  </html>
```

What I need is the value of dir in html that is "LTR".

I tried "document.querySelector("html").dir" from inside iframe's code and it returns "" as it looks for the second html tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's in a different document, you can't find it starting with `document`.

But assuming your iframe and its parent are in the same origin, you can access it via `parent.document.querySelector('html').dir` or more directly `parent.document.documentElement.dir` (as `documentElement` in an HTML document is the `html` element):

```
alert(parent.document.documentElement.dir);
```

You wouldn't have access to that if the iframe and its parent aren't in the same origin.

Comment: @Gothdo: Good dupe; done. Still some useful additional info above, so I'll leave it.